# Data type conversion error between SQL Server int and MS Access VBA long data types

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Using an ms access 2007 form I am trying to manipulate a particular record from a linked SQL Server 2005 table.

```vb
'Form code
 Private Sub orderid_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
 Dim idv As Long
 idv = Me.orderid.Value
 '...
 Call manipulateRecord(idv)
 end sub

 'module code
 Public Sub manipulateRecord(pidp As Long)
     Dim rs0 As Recordset
 Set rs0 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(dbSeeChanges, "select * from  tableorders where idorder=" & pidp)
 'this line produces the error "Run-time error '3421' data type conversion error"
 'replacing the query with "select idorder from tableorders where idorder=" & pidp  , produces the same error so that there is a mismatch between sqlserver int and  vba long
 'Setting pidp as integer produces overflow error instead
 '...
 end sub
```

`tableorders` is a linked sqlserver 2005 table

`idorder` field is of type int

How can get recognized the SQL Server 2005 int in MA Access 2007 VBA?

Comment: Try to link table to MS Access and work with it via Access itself, through queries and so on. And if you link table directly, would it work?

Comment: I first created and tested the whole functionality with an identical local model ms-access table and it works fine

Comment: I think problem is in another field, something like MEMO, nvarchar over 255 symbols and so on. Just try to link it to Access via standard tool

Comment: Er, the order of arguments to `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset` is wrong. It's `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from  tableorders where idorder=" & pidp, dbSeeChanges)`. I'm counting that as a typo.

Comment: yes, changing the order of the arguments removed the data type conversion error, you may want to place your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with long and int - your parameters are in the wrong order.

```vb
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(dbSeeChanges, "select * from  tableorders where idorder=" & pidp)
```

must be

```vb
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from  tableorders where idorder=" & pidp, , dbSeeChanges)
```